# Issues creating an if else statement for rounding with a loop in R

Tags: r

I'm struggling with code for an R class. We are working on loops and I'm supposed to round numbers within a dataframe up if they have a decimal greater than .6, round down if a decimal <0.4 and leave alone if in between. I cannot get this to work.

Dataframe:

```
 set.seed(12)
 df<-data.frame(rgamma(n=20,shape=4,scale=2),runif(n=20),rnorm(n=20),paste("Observation",1:20))
 colnames(df)<-c("V1","V2","V3","Obs")
```

Here is the code I've tried:

```
rounddf<-rep(nrow(df),ncol(df)-1) 
for (i in 1:ncol(df)-1) 
{
for (j in 1:nrow(df)) 
 {
  if (i>0.6)
   {rounddf[i]<-ceiling(df[i]) 
    } else if (i<0.4){rounddf[i]<-floor(df[i])}
  }
}
rounddf
```

Comment: the "i" in your if statements are not the values in the dataframe, but only the indices of the first for loop

Comment: Beware, in your code, `> 1:ncol(df)-1` is `[1] 0 1 2 3`. You mean `1:(ncol(df)-1)`.

Comment: Also, you may want to check out `?floor` (which should help you find the decimal number) and logical indexing (e.g. [here](http://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/vectorindexing.html))

Comment: Thank you all, though I'm still having issues. Jannic, how can I designate the `i` in the `if` statements to be values from the dataframe?

Comment: Any other help/advice?

Comment: You should only loop through columns and use vectorized `ifelse()`. Also, are you restricted to only using `for` loops for this assignment? I see some possible apply solutions: `lapply`, `mapply`, `sapply`...?

Comment: @Parfait, I was planning to use an ifelse statement, but was told not to by the professor - he wants an element-wise if else statement. In trying to loop through just columns I created this: 
     rounddf<-rep(nrow(df), (ncol(df)-1))
     for (i in 1:(ncol(df)-1))
{
         if (df[i]>0.6)
        {
          rounddf<-ceiling(df[i])} 
    else if (df[i]<0.4)  {
      rounddf<-floor(df[i])}
      else {rounddf<-(df[i])}
    }`
I feel like I'm getting closer, but not there. The result was just the rounding of the 3rd column of df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to create an empty data frame and populate it by using the i and j in the for loop to index those values in the new data frame.
This code will do exactly what you want. You also have to make sure to reduce your numbers into fractions so that the part that is larger than 1 is hidden. Then you can use if else statements to evaluate them.

```
   set.seed(12)
   df<-data.frame(rgamma(n=20,shape=4,scale=2),
   runif(n=20),rnorm(n=20),paste("Observation",1:20))
   colnames(df)<-c("V1","V2","V3","Obs")


   newdf <-data.frame( V1=rep(0,20), V2=rep(0,20), V3=rep(0,20))



   df <- df[,1:3, drop=TRUE]

    for (i in 1:ncol(df)) 
   {
   for (j in 1:nrow(df)) 
   {n <- df[j,i]
   whole <- floor(df[j,i])
   fraction <- n-whole
   if(fraction > .60)  newdf[j,i] <- ceiling(df[j,i])
   if(fraction < .40) newdf[j,i] <- floor(df[j,i])
   if((fraction > .4) & (fraction < .6)) newdf[j,i] <- df[j,i] }}
```

Comment: Many thanks Maxwell!
I do have a question. Could you not move the `n<-df[j,i] statement outside of the loop? Or does that not make any sense?

Comment: The n <-df[j,i] statement needs to be in the loop. Otherwise j and i are not defined as numbers and therefore are of no use in indexing. R would interpret that as the jth row and ith column, which of course, is gibberish unless i and j have been defined. The for loop makes I and J assume all the possible values of the data frame 'df' and uses that property to populate a new data frame with the same indexes.